# QML: reference of parent from cursor delegate = Unqualified access

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

For such code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15

TextInput {
    id: textInput
    cursorDelegate: Rectangle {
        visible: textInput.activeFocus && textInput.selectionStart === textInput.selectionEnd
    }
}
```

I got warning from qmllint:

```
Warning: Test2.qml:6:18: Unqualified access
        visible: textInput.activeFocus && textInput.selectionStart === textInput.selectionEnd
                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

Any how to fix this warning and what the problem with access to `textInput` from `cursorDelegate`?